# How to solve a merge conflict with composer.lock using git flow?

Tags: git, version-control, composer-php, git-merge, git-flow

I am working on a Laravel project and using git-flow to manage my changes. My **develop** branch is two commits ahead of a feature branch I recently completed named **feature/registration-captcha**. I want to merge this feature branch into the develop branch.

[image]

The most recent commit I made which has since been merged into the develop branch was simply running `composer update` to update a package which had a bug in it. So, the `composer.lock` file has of course been modified.

The **feature/registration-captcha** feature branch consisted of adding a captcha package and the captcha UI to a registration page. So, this also modified the `composer.lock` file.

When sitting on the feature branch I have tried merging the commit, from Source Tree, by selecting **Repository > Git Flow > Finish Feature**, then selecting the following options on the **Finish Feature** pop up:

[image]

I am then presented with the following message:

[image]

This results in a `composer.lock` file with the merge conflicts which need resolving. I thought the best way to approach this would be to remove `composer.lock` and create a fresh updated copy by running `composer update` or `composer update --lock`, adding the unstaged `composer.lock` file and committing the change. After doing this my commits look like this:

[image]

When running `git status` from the command line I am shown the following:

```
c:\my-project (HEAD detached at 2a9ff12)
λ git status
rebase in progress; onto 3070450
You are currently rebasing branch 'feature/registration-captcha' on '3070450'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

So I thought the correct thing to do was to run `git rebase --continue`, after which I receive the following message:

```
c:\my-project (HEAD detached at 2a9ff12)
λ git rebase --continue
Applying: add non captcha to registration page
No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else
already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch.

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

If I run `git status` again I am shown the same message as the last time I ran `git status`.

So I am now wondering:

- What am I supposed to be doing here to finish the rebase/merge?
- Am I doing it all wrong?
- Should I be handling the conflicts that may arise from updating packages differently?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You should not delete composer.lock and do a composer update in this case - never! the merge conflict is there for a reason. in your approach you updated now a lot more packages than you wanted to. the easiest way to proceed in these cases is to accept the foreign composer.lock, throwing away your version. then you need to remember which packages you updated in your branch (pro-tip: create a git commit for your update statement and write the statement in the comment) and run composer update <packages> explicitly. with the pro-tip this step can be automated

Answer (score 2):

> Am I doing it all wrong?

As git is very flexible regarding workflows, there is always more than one way to do it. ;)

What went wrong in this specific case – if I understand the sequence of your actions correctly – is that you started the rebase before the merge was finished, because you wanted to use it to resolve the merge conflict. That is how you ended up in the detached head state.

> Should I be handling the conflicts that may arise from updating packages differently?

If you encounter a merge conflict you are in state where the merge is started, but not finished. It can be aborted (but then there is no merging) or finished (resolve conflict and commit changes).

With `composer.lock` I would first try to resolve the merge conflict manually, as the conflicts should be very obvious: some packages updated, another added – the conflict is maybe a couple of lines changed on both sides. `composer.lock` is a file in JSON format, as you have the correctly working versions from both branches available, this should be easy to fix. Maybe SourceTree offers a conflict resolution tool here (I do not use it), but this is also possible in a text editor ([git marks the conflicting blocks](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_how_conflicts_are_presented)) or with tools like [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) and [VimDiff](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html) and others (which can be called by [`git mergetool`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool)) and present you the 3 or 4 text windows: the versions from the two branches, the conflict resolution window with the current state (here you make the changes) and (optional) the base version of both branches and for a side-by-side comparison. Save it, test it ([`composer install`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install) should tell you if something is wrong with the `composer.lock` file, or [`composer validate`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#validate)). Then add and commit – git still knows the commit belongs to the merge.

Another method of conflict resolution in this specific case (the files were not manually edited but by a programm and you know what was done on both branches) would be: while you are at the merge, presented with the conflict, checkout the `composer.lock` from develop (just this file), and run your composer command that added the new package like you did in the branch, add and commit. Result is like you did run the update and package adding in sequence.

> What am I supposed to be doing here to finish the rebase/merge?

If no other changes are present in your workdir or detached head, and develop is also still at the state in the description, I would start over with the merge:

- `git rebase --abort` if rebase is still ongoing
- `git merge --abort` if merge is still ongoing
- checkout develop
- merge feature branch again
- resolve the conflict in one of the ways described
- commit the merge (including the conflict resolving changes), push, etc.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. The conflicts in composer.lock were about 28 or so lines with varying dates which were basically the package's latest version vs older version and I opted for the latest version in all cases. I made the merge, but couldn't seem to progress with the rebase so ended up doing rebase skip. Still a bit confused as to why that was happening.

Comment: You don't need the rebase in this case, since you brought together the two branches with the merge. I will clarify the answer.